# Session returns undefined sometimes but fixes when I restart the page

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session

app.js:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {

// res.locals.ctoken = req.csrfToken();
res.locals.query = req.query;
res.locals.numeral = numeral;
res.locals.moment = moment;

res.locals.messages = req.session.messages;
delete req.session.messages;

//secret message
if (req.session && req.session.secret_message) {
    res.locals.secret_message = req.session.secret_message;
} else {
    res.locals.secret_message = false
}

//admin login
if (req.session && req.session.admin) {
    res.locals.admin = req.session.admin;
}

// products cart
if (req.session && req.session.products) {
    res.locals.products = req.session.products;
} else {
    req.session.products = [];
}

// user login
if (req.session && req.session.user) {
    res.locals.user = req.session.user;
} else {
    res.locals.user = false;
}

next();

});
```

Error that is being thrown:
[image]

views/partials/navbar.ejs:

```
<%

var pricesArray = []

for(var i = 0; i < products.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < cart.length; j++){
        if ( products[i] == cart[j].product_id) {

            var originalPrice = cart[j].product_price
            var discount = cart[j].product_discount
            var afterPrice = originalPrice * ( (100-discount) / 100 )

            pricesArray.push(cart[j].product_discount? afterPrice : cart[j].product_price)

        }
    }
}

var subtotal = pricesArray.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

var cartTotalLength = products.length;

%>
```

So basically, sometimes, whenever the products session is empty, it's throwing this error and when I restart the page, it goes away. I have no idea why this is happening, I'm guessing there's a problem in app.js file. I tried to do this inside navbar.ejs file:

```
<% if (typeof products == "undefined") products = false %>
```

But this might not be the best solution, any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Just set `req.session.products = [];` to an empty array as a default and then if there's `req.session.products` assign that value to `req.session.products`. This way the `products` will always be defined.

Comment: @Molda Sorry I couldn't quite understand what you meant. I'm already returning req.session.products = []; if the products session array is empty...

Comment: but it's `req.locals.products` what you get as `products` variable in your .ejs file. So this line `req.session.products = [];` should be `req.locals.products = [];`

Comment: @Molda Ohhh. Right right right! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Molda Also, I think there should be both req.session.products = []; and res.locals.products = [];